# Python programming with file

Tags: python

I need help with a problem concerning the code below.

```
with open ("Premier_League.txt", "r+") as f:
        i= int(input("Please put in your result! \n"))
        data = f.readlines()
        print(data)
        data[i] = int(data[i])+1
        f.seek(0) # <-- rewind to the beginning
        f.writelines(str(data))
        f.truncate() # <-- cut any leftovers from the old version
        print(data)
        data[i] = str(data)
```

For example if the file
Premier_League.txt contains:

```
1
2
3
```

and as I run the program and `choose i as 0`
that gives me:

```
[2, '2\n', '3']
```

and saves it to the already existing file (and deletes the old content)
But after that I cannot run the program again and it gives me this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "[2, '2\\n', '3']"
```

**My question is: How do I make the new file content suitable to go into the program again?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this approach:

```
with open('Premier_League.txt', 'r+') as f:
    data = [int(line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()] # [1, 2, 3]
    f.seek(0)

    i = int(input("Please put in your result! \n"))

    data[i] += 1  # e.g. if i = 1, data now [1, 3, 3]

    for line in data:
        f.write(str(line) + "\n")

    f.truncate()
```

Comment: data = [int(line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()] # [1, 2, 3]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @PythonGirl make sure you reset your `Premier_League.txt` file... if it contains '2\\n' as in your question, you'll receive that error.

Comment: Thank so you freaking much! You have saved my day!

Comment: @PythonGirl glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

f readlines() read all content in a list as a string,if you want write back those contents as int

```
data=[]
with open ("Premier_League.txt", "r+") as f:
        i= int(input("Please put in your result! \n"))
        data = f.readlines()

with open ("Premier_League.txt", "w") as f:            
        for j in data:
            f.write(str(int(j)+1))
            #or do this to make it more clean,these lines are comments
            #j=int(j)+1
            #f.write(str(j))



         # <-- cut any leftovers from the old version
print(data)
```

Note that,once you open a file,if you don't close it,your written contents can be lost,whatever you want to do with data,your have to do it in the second writing method .Also notice the change from r to w in `with open ("Premier_League.txt", "w")` for writing

Comment: It only tells me that "data is not defined"

Comment: Do you see on the top that data is declared as data=[],right on the top of my codes

Comment: You don't need to close the file when using a context manager. Nor is it necessary to open the file twice.

Comment: @flevinkelming,true,i forgot

Comment: tells me: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int

Answer (score 1):

Following my solution:

```
with open ("Premier_League.txt", "r+") as f:
        i= int(input("Please put in your result! \n"))
        # here strip wrong chars from input 
        data = f.readlines()
        print(data)
        # here added the str(..) conversion
        data[i] = str(int(data[i].strip())+1) + '\n'
        f.seek(0) # <-- rewind to the beginning
        # the str(data) is wrong, data is a list!
        f.writelines(data)
        # I don't think this is necessary
        # f.truncate() # <-- cut any leftovers from the old version
        print(data)
        # i think this is not necessary
        # data[i] = str(data)
```

Comment: Hi I tried your solution (and put i=0) and this happened, file contained ['0', '1', '2', '3'], first run gave me ['1', '1', '2', '3'] which is exactly what I wanted!, the second run gave me ['22344', '4', ''] which is clearly wrong...

Comment: Oh I missed that writelines does not automatically add the newline char at the end of each element. I updated my answer.